# Flutter : How to block full screen video in webview?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I use "webview_flutter: ^1.0.7" plugin in my flutter app to open a webview but I have a problem when a website launch a video after a click anywhere on the screen an it's open in fullscreen. How to disable it without disable javascript ? I want to play the video but not in fullscreen

I can't use "AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy" because there is an action

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to update html file:

```
    String hmtlCode = (await http.get(initialUrl)).body;
    # edit this code (either append to string, or find and replace)
```

https://itqna.net/questions/80033/how-disable-full-screen-html5-video-any-browser (html example how to disable full screen)

and then feed this html to webview

```
String hmtlCode = ....;
String url = Uri.dataFromString(hmtlCode, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')).toString();
WebView(
   initialUrl: url,
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "feature" with ios. You need to disable the full screen ios/safari option when your app is running on an ios device.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.dart';

...

@override
Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
  late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
  if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
    params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    );
  } else {
    params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
  }

  final controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params)
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(YOUR_URL_HERE));
  return WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
}
```